# Programatically check if two threads belong to the same process in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

How do I check if two threads belong to same or different processes programatically? This is the piece of code I have written:

```
public class MyThread {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestThread1 obj1 = new TestThread1();
        TestThread2 obj2 = new TestThread2();
        System.out.println("Current thread:" + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        Thread t1 = new Thread(obj1);
        t1.start();
        Thread t2 = new Thread(obj2);
        t2.start();


    }
}

class TestThread1 implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run () {
        for(int i=0; i<1000 ;i++) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
            }
            System.out.println("Current thread:" + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        }
    }
}

class TestThread2 implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run () {
        for(int i=0; i<1000 ;i++) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
            }
            System.out.println("Current thread:" + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        }
    }
}
```

Here what I understand is thread t1 being created as part of process TestThread1 and thread t2 being created as part of TestThread2 process. But how do i check this programatically?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. If both threads are present in the JRE, then both are part of the same Java process. That is, even if this class was run from two different VMs, the only knowledge a VM has about other VM threads is via IPC.

Comment: Your question is unclear. It seems you've misunderstood what is meant by process and thread. Also, objects don't belong to threads. Also, Java does not consider which thread created any other thread. There is no parent-child relationship.

Comment: My bad, incorrectly worded. Let me close this and open another one.

Comment: @vmr how about editing this one..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mixed the concept of threads and processes.

> thread t1 being created as part of process TestThread1 and thread t2
>   being created as part of TestThread2

Your `TestThread1` and `TestThread2` are just runnables, that hold information what action should be done by thread. Your `t1` and `t2` are actual threads, they run in the same process, because you started them in one application. All threads in the application run in same java process, so you can't have a situation where you have two threads referecens and they belong to different processes.

If you start another java application, it will run in a different process, but you won't be able to compare two threads from different processes in a single context.

Comment: You are right, i got confused. Thanks for sorting this out.

Answer (score 2):

There is something wrong with your understanding or your use of terminology.

> Here what I understand is thread `t1` being created as part of process `TestThread1` and thread `t2` being created as part of `TestThread2` process.

First of all, some terminology:

- `TestThread1` and `TestThread2` are classes not processes.
- The values in `obj1` and `obj2` are not processes either.  They are instances of the `TestThread1` and `TestThread2` classes respectively.

If I interpret your question correctly, you are actually asking if there is a way to find out if `t1` and `t2` share a single `Runnable` instance.  Unfortunately, there isn't a way to do that in pure Java.  A `Thread` object's `Runnable` is a private field and there is no public getter for retrieving it<sup>1</sup>.

On the other hand, if you are *really* asking about processes ...

When you run the application, there will be only one process, and both threads will belong to it.

---

<sup>1 - It is possible to use *nasty* reflection to retrieve the private field's value, but it is a bad idea.  You should look for a way to do whatever you are trying to do that doesn't entail this test ...</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is an easier way, but you could call `getStackTrace()` on a thread and then inspect it (search for the `run` method's frame). However, this will work only for live threads.

PS You use wrong terminology here, what you refer to is not a process, it is just a class that defines the `run` method which is executed by the thread.

Comment: All Threads which is part of same process share system resource like Heap Memory and other resource but each Thread has its own Exception handler and own stack.